# Delete all slaves with an object in HQL

Tags: java, hql

I use following HQL query to delete a specific object in my database.

```
delete from com.ranking.Footballclub where id = 1
```

The problem I encounter when I do this, it breaks a foreign key.

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The DELETE
>   statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_VKLC3OLNFZIT2FCYMMKDO2ERZ4". The conflict occurred in database
>   "sports", table "dbo.FOOTBALL_PLAYER", column 'CLUB_ID'

A sport teams has a slave of players. I could first delete all players before I delete the Footballclub. But a Footballclub has more than just players. It has for example a list of employees, transfers,... Their foreign keys will break as well.

For this case I'm looking for something in HQL to delete all slave fields in 1 statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the data base explicitly, or mark the required Child entity with the annotation `@org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete`.

It will automatically adds the *on delete* to schema during the schema generation. like -

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "YOUR_PARENT", 
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)    
 @org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete(
            action = @org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
 private List<YOUR_CHILD> CHILDS;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) annotation at your Entity and delete it through entity manager. There is no option to do it with hql. Or use constraint in your DDL (foreign key delete cascade);